# PHP Mysql always NEED to return 5 rows even 3rows present in table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi i need 5 rows count always in `Mysql select query`

I My current output is

```
 

my query
----------------------
$query = mysql_query("select * from table_name where  MOBILE='$mobile_no' order by ID  LIMIT 5 ");
----------------------
Result
----------------------
ARUN - 987654321
VINO - 987654321
RAJA - 987654321

-------------------

But I need like this (Need to return empty rows)
----------------------
ARUN - 987654321
VINO - 987654321
RAJA - 987654321
0    - 0
0    - 0
-------------------
```

So that I can create `html table row` (always 5 rows) `text box` with empty value inside the

```
  while loop -----  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

Comment: why don't you get the number of returned rows and then add them yourself instead of editing the statement?

Comment: count the number of row if less than 5 than add  5 - countRow in table with 0 0 values

Comment: Programmatically i need to add html table rows. later dynamically i need to change the limit

Comment: select query some times return only one row that time i need to add 4 rows text box with empty value. some time query return 3 rows that time need to add only 2 rows... could you understand?

Comment: @ aleksv do you have any other idea about this? is it possible in mysql?

Comment: database result has nothing to do with your back end code, nor with your templating. handle this in your php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop in php and a counter in the loop. If the count is less then 5, then you fill the text box with nothing. It will give you something like that

```
$count = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    // Fill your text box
    $count+=1;
}
for($i=count; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    // Fill your text box with empty string or whatever.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you requested a sql solution here it is: (but I do not recommend using it)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, column1
          FROM table_name
         WHERE mobile = '$mobile_no'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL)
       AS tab
order by tab.ID  LIMIT 5
```

but you need to explicitly select all the columns from your table and in the select statements add as many NULL columns as you selected in your main statement. I didn't test it since I don't know your columns

Comment: I solved my self by using row count and after while loop i used a for loop :) It works fine for me... anyway thanks for the answer (I didn't test the above code)

Answer (score 0):

simply add 2 more textboxes in html page. and not send any value or send null values in your database

Comment: select query some times return only one row that time i need to add 4 rows text box with empty value. some time query return 3 rows that time need to add only 2 rows... could you understand?